# Lamdify a function keeping some symbols

Tags: python, numpy, sympy

I'm trying to lamdify a SymPy expression to a NumPy evaluated function, but keeping some symbols of the original expression. It works for some simple expressions

```
>>> x,y,z=sympy.symbols('x y z')
>>> expr1=(x+y)*z
>>> func1=sympy.lambdify((x,y),expr1,modules='numpy')
>>> func1(1.,1.)
2.0*z
```

but when I try some other more complicated like:

```
>>> expr2=sympy.exp((x+y)*z)
>>> func2=sympy.lambdify((x,y),expr2,modules='numpy')
>>> func2(1.,1.)
Traceback (most recent call last):
File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
File "<string>", line 1, in <lambda>
AttributeError: 'Mul' object has no attribute 'exp'
```

I get this error. Any suggestion would be welcome!

Comment: Why do you want it to be a `numpy` evaluated function?

Comment: There are hundred of operations to perform inside the symbolic expression when doing the substitution. Doing that with sympy.subs takes a lot of time.

Comment: Please open an issue about this here. https://github.com/sympy/sympy/issues

Answer (score 0):

Have you checked whether using "sympy" in modules would do the job? It seems to work on your little example. We just need to know whether it will give you what you expect from the "numpy" option.

I had this issue before working with complex numbers in polar form. Using "sympy" just solve the problem and, until now, I've been able to work with them without troubles.

```
import sympy as sp

x, y, z = sp.symbols("x y z")
expr2 = sp.exp((x + y) * z)
func2 = sp.lambdify((x, y), expr2, modules="sympy")
func2(1., 1)
```